# How to use my Linux as DVI/HDMI switch? Where 2PC use 1 screen, depending on priority one PC output gets render

Tags: linux, video, display, hdmi

I have done this with triple head Linux (it works!!), which is not my current case, but just to explain.

[image]

I have this scenario, which i need to solve with Linux.

[image]

How can i take 2PC output and display it to 1 screen 
on-demand like source switching depending on request. So whenever i change source it shows PC1 output only and when i switch back it will show PC2 output only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that DDC [(Display Data Channel)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) could be the answer Try this [DDCControl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ddccontrol/)

from the config file (options.xml)

```
-<control name="Input Source Select" address="0x60" type="list" id="inputsource">
 <value name="Analog" id="analog"/> 
 <value name="Digital" id="digital"/> 
</control> 
-<control name="Autoselect Input Source" address="0xe2" type="list" id="autosource">        
<value name="Automatic" id="auto" value="0"/> 
<value name="Manual" id="manual" value="1"/>
</control>
```

Comment: DDCControl, can tell my display screen to change now to DVI or VGA?

Comment: The DDC standard is older than that. What's the point with being old and unmaintained? It's just a small tool, not a nuclear reactor control system.

Comment: WITH ALL RESPECT :) Just that its old does not mean bad, old is gold and genius and robust. What was making me confuse is that, can DDC send the signal to the monitor "Please change the source now from VGA to DVI and vice versa, ofcource if the monitor is compatible with VESA/DDC"

Comment: I don't know if it will work "out of the box" but from the config file I can tell that the commands exists. See edit in answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your monitor supports Virtual Control Panel (VCP) feature x60, then you can use it to change the video input. But keep in mind that the command must be issued from the computer currently connected.  So if computer A is currently connected to input 1 on the monitor and computer B is connected to input 2, and input 1 is currently active, then computer A can issue the command to switch the monitor to input 2.   To switch it back again the command must be issued from computer B.

The acceptable arguments for feature x60 will vary from monitor to monitor, depending on what physical inputs exist. See the VESA Moniotor Control Command Set (MCCS) spec for details.

Feature x60 is a standard feature defined in the MCCS spec.  Feature xe2 described in the prior post is in the range reserved for manufacturers.   It may mean one thing on one monitor, something else on a second, and nothing at all on a third.